# Efficient way for finding attributes in a table which belong together, based on second table

Tags: sql, join, informix

I have two tables:

```
person
----------
id  name
1   peter
2   paul
3   mary
4   george
5   andy
```

and

```
living
-------
id  key
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   2
```

What would be the most efficient query for finding all ids in *person* which belong together, if I know the *name*. Let's say I want to find out: "Who is Mary living with"? In *person*, Mary's id is 3. I check *living* for the key, which belongs to Mary, which is 2. Now I can retrieve all ids in *living* which go with key 2, and I have the ids which live together with Mary.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT p2.name
  FROM person p1
  JOIN living l1
    ON p1.id = l1.id
  JOIN living l2
    ON l1.key = l2.key
  JOIN person p2
    ON l2.id = p2.id
 WHERE p1.name = 'mary'
```

Is there a better way? The result seems to be fine, but it doesn't feel right to perform three `JOINS`.

Comment: The three joins looks fine to me, I'm not seeing a more obvious way to do it. What you're basically asking is "get me all the keys in `living` that are associated with the id of _mary_ (excluding _mary's_ keys) and using those keys, get me the names of people from `person`. Here's a SQLFiddle for it - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/002c8/6

Comment: I don't see other simple way to work with this, my suggestion is remove the "ansi" code and write as non-ansi standard, this way able to the database/optimization choose better way to fetch the data. Off course if have the appropriate indexes will help a lot.

Comment: Just an idea popup at my mind is use the "connect by" resource, but the sql will be more complicate to understand and I don't believe will be better performance.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do in you case is:

```
 DEFINE name CHAR(15);
 LET name = 'mary'
define keyValue char(10);
select l.key into keyValue from person p left outer join living l on p.id= l.id and p.name= name

select p.*, l.* from person p left outer join living l on p.id=l.id 
where key= keyValue
```

I have never used Informix before, however the the best solution should be along those lines or at least close to them. 
Thanks

Comment: This whole code isn't valid as informix statement. With lot of corrections maybe will work into procedure...